# 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045]

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

i do not know why lately when I try to make a regitro in the database (using laravel), I get this error:

```
'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE [HY000] [1045] Access denied for user' homestead '@' localhost '( using password: YES) '.
```

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=pruebas
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

in .env file is properly configured. What more could be ??

thanks.

Comment: check it like this, go to config\database.php edit from connections array. does it work?

Comment: which os are you using. is it windows?

Answer (score 0):

the solution for this error, if everything is properly configured, is to restart the local server, in my case xampp